# how could I find document field type in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, bson

the key of `$type` used to search operation which filter by pointed BSON type. I can use $type try the every BSON type to get the field's type. Is there a straight ways to show document fields type? thanks.

Comment: When you retrieve a BSON document in your application, the type information of all fields should be more or less preserved, depending on which programming language and database driver you are using.

Comment: Thank you remind @Philipp. driver contains many info about saved data but I can't always run a driver to get the type info because it is not convenient.Just now,I find some mongo GUI software,it seems great, but I also hope a way look in mongo shell.Or... not exist yet?